# VBA sub doesn't select the range of a specific Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I just want to get the range from A1:A80 from a sheet called "Children" but I debug it, it gets nothing. Here's my code below:

```
   Dim wks2 As Worksheet
   Dim children As Range
   Worksheets("Children").Activate
   Set wks2 = Worksheets("Children")
   Set children = wks2.Range("A1:A80")
   ResetChild (children) //The sub that I want to call. Explanation bellow.
```

In the function ResetChild I want to delete all the sheets in my Workbook, that have names equal to the first column of the sheet Children. (A1:A80) So here's my sub below:

```
Sub ResetChild(children As Range)
Call DisableCalculations
Dim cell As Range
    
For Each cell In children
    Set childrenSheet = Worksheets(cell.Value)
        If (DoesSheetExist(childrenSheet)) Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(childrenSheet).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code just sets variables, there is nothing to "get" - Where are you doing something with the `children` variable?

Comment: This line `Set children = wks2.Range("A1:A80")` just means that the variable `children` refers to the exact same as `wks2.Range("A1:A80")` does. Nothing more. Please [edit] and clarify what your actual issue is. Also see [mcve]. • Note that it is not necessary to activate a sheet `Worksheets("Children").Activate` unless you really want the user to see that.

Comment: I edited the question, please check it again. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work.
How do you know that it returns nothhing?
put the row in the end of your code

```
   Debug.Print children.Count
```

if it returns >0 then all ok and children is the range object with data

Comment: It gets the range thank you. But I have another question. Is it possible to pass this range to another sub?

Comment: declare the variables children and wks2  as public  in declarations and operate with the object in another sub

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
Sub DeleteChildren()
    Dim children As Range
    Dim oChildSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vChildName

    Set children = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Children").Range("A1:A80")        
    For Each vChildName In children
        Set oChildSheet = GetChildSheet(CStr(vChildName))
        If Not oChildSheet Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Call oChildSheet.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next vChildName
End Sub

Function GetChildSheet(sChildName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Set GetChildSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sChildName)
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    Debug.Print "Child sheet not found: " & sChildName
End Function
```